# How to use the D3 Diverging Stacked Bar Chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to implement the Diverging Stacked Bar Chart: [click here](http://bl.ocks.org/wpoely86/e285b8e4c7b84710e463)

I however I'm finding it difficult to understand how to set this up in a local environment. I've downloaded the code but I want to be able to change things on load where as it seems to be a static html template.

I'm basically asking for a link to a tutorial on how to use this lib as the documentation is awful or a tutorial on here.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=d3js+tutorials

Comment: Thanks I didn't think of this